# How to use a cell magic to selectively run cells in IPython/Jupyter notebooks?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I would like to create a Jupiter notebook that allows me to selectively run cells based on a local variable. For example, I define a boolean variable `plot` in the first cell:

```
plot=False
```

and in subsequent cells I have the following conditional code:

```
if plot: 
   df.plot()
   ..... # some other plots
```

To have a more elegant syntax, I was thinking about a custom cell magic to basically read the local variable: `plot` and run the cell code based on its value. Is it possible for a magic to read a local variable and modify the code based on the value of that variable?